# Ошибка под отладкой `The name 't' doe not exist in current context`

Tags: c#, unity3d, rider

Столкнулся с проблемой, что под отладкой не могу посмотреть содержимое переменных, например `List<int> t1` `int[] t2` и `int t3`. Сообщается ошибка: `The name 't' doe not exist in current context`.
Переменные объявляются и затем инициализируются через `out` внутри другой функции. Там они действительно инициализируются.
Чисто для проверки вручную присвоил значения `int[] t2 = new[] {5, 6, 7};` и всё равно та же ошибка, когда смотришь в них под отладкой.
Однако сами данные в переменных присутствуют! Этот вывод я делаю исходя из того, что, если их вывести в консоль `foreach (var i in t) Debug.Log(i);`, то они выводятся нормально.
Подскажите, как решить проблему?

UPD: Товарищи... `t` в сообщении ошибки было написано умышленно, с целью обобщить ошибки на каждую из переменных и не писать: "... например `List<int> t1` `int[] t2` и `int t3`. Сообщаются ошибки: `The name 't1' does not exist in current context.`, `The name 't2' does not exist in current context.`, `The name 't3' does not exist in current context.`" соответственно.
Но всё же это пришлось написать!

UPD2: Код следующий:

```
private IEnumerator Update() {
    yield return null;
    while (true) {
        if (!_sourceDataIsReady) yield return null;
        _sourceDataIsReady = false;
        // кое-что делаю...
        bool chessboardFound;
        Point2f[] corners;
        chessboardFound = Cv2.FindChessboardCorners(_matGrayFrame, _pattern.size,
            out corners, ChessboardFlags.FastCheck);
        // вот здесь, после выполнения функции,
        // не было видно переменных chessboardFound и corners

        // и снова делаю что-то
    }
}
```

Для теста использовал следующий код:

```
private IEnumerator Update() {
        yield return null;
        while (true) {
            List<int> t1 = new List<int>() {5,6,7};
            int[] t2 = new [] {5,6,7};
            int t3 = 5
            for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
                Debug.Log($"List i: {t1[i]}");
                Debug.Log($"Array i: {t2[i]}");
            }
            Debug.Log($"Int: {t3}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Потому что они называются не как t, а t1, t2, t3.

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, кусок кода, который вы отлаживаете

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Товарищи... `t` в сообщении ошибки было написано умышленно с целью обобщить ошибки на каждую из переменных и не писать: "... например `List<int> t1` `int[] t2` и `int t3`. Сообщаются ошибки: `The name 't1' does not exist in current context.`, `The name 't2' does not exist in current context.`, `The name 't3' does not exist in current context.` соответственно." Но всё же это пришлось написать!

Comment: @GoodSimon а можешь приложить код?

Comment: @alladuh выложил

Comment: @AndreiKhotko добавил код

Comment: Такое сообщение может появлятся, когда вы ставите точку остановки уже после того, как переменная была выгружена из памяти или когда ее время жизни уже было закончено. К примеру, ваш enumerator может запросто не отработать за пределами самой этой функции, только внутри пока существуют ссылки. К примеру, если ставить точку внутри вашего foreach в коде `foreach (var i in t) Debug.Log(i);` и можно `t` прочитать на ней, то проблема скорее всего не в IDE окружения, а в использовании дебаггера.

Comment: Вы пользуетесь методом "StartCoroutine"?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko да

Comment: @AlexKrass действительно, точку останова ставил внутри foreach и вылазила ошибка, но содержимое выводилось. Правильно ли я Вас понял что в этом случае это просто проблема/ошибка в работе отладчика?